# Sidebar not shown only in IE 7? and ONLY not shown in one specific page?

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

Okay I have this website that I was working using Wordpress. I wrote some custom Page template for this CMS. But I'm not aware of that there is [only this page's sidebar doesn't show in IE 7](http://www.patentable.com/web2/index.php/lawyers/) This page is under the lawyer.php template.

I don't know if its the template page problem, or is the CSS that has the problem.

Here is the screen shoot not working in IE 7

[alt text http://www.sfu.ca/~qha6/in_IE_7.png](http://www.sfu.ca/~qha6/in_IE_7.png)

and working in all other browser.

[alt text http://www.sfu.ca/~qha6/in_all_other_browser.png](http://www.sfu.ca/~qha6/in_all_other_browser.png)

also noticed that the footer on this particular page doesn't display properly

help Please ! I just can't figure out why its displaying like this.

Answer (score 1):

[Validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.patentable.com/web2/index.php/lawyers/) shows that you're missing the closing tag for `<div id="wrapper">`. The unescaped ampersand errors aren't that important, unless you're looking for perfect valdiation; they shouldn't effect display.